# Event SOAP API Endpoint date fields are always same

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Event endpoints have `created_date`, `modified_date` and `event_date` as retrievable properties but I see that all three dates are exactly same for an event. Does  an event ever gets modified once created ?

Comment: in your retrieve, are you including these as properties in your request? If not, they will only display the default date. The retrieve will always return all the fields, but will only fill in the actual values on the ones inside your request.

Comment: @Gortonington yes I am including these as properties in my request. Have you ever noticed a `modified date` different than `event date` ?